# Extract specific string from String

Tags: java

Hii friends I am beginner in java. I am getting string from `InputStream` in the format like:

```
aD1bD2cD3dD4eD5fD6g
```

where `D1`,`D2`,`D3`... are data and small letters `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g` are identifier so I can identify data between `a` and `b` and `c` and so on.

Now the problem is that I am getting more than one data pattern with spaces in between. But I need extract only first data from it. For example, consider data received as

```
a-674b-26c96d-662e-39f93g a74b-2c96d66e-39f86g a-84b-96c96d562e-99f93g
```

then I need to extract only first data from this entire data string that is

```
a-674b-26c96d-662e-39f93g
```

Please help me.

Comment: You are doing your brain a disservice by not attempting. You'd be surprised what you can do when you make a conscious effort. You should look into the `split()` method, but it's far more rewarding to at least make an attempt and then come here to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
String[] params = data.split(" ");
String firstString = params[0];
```

`split()` function will split your whole string using space as delimiter, resulting in array of strings. First element of the array is the string you are looking for.

Comment: please explain me How it will work??for understanding

Comment: I did, check edited post.